# android XML layout to fit any screen (Linear or Relative)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

Good day to all, I have a Linear Layout that looks like this

[image: Linea Layout]

in the fragment area there is a fragment for a google map, what I want is to have a layout that make the fragment to use the available space in the screen without leaving the rest of the elements pushed out, so in some screens the map will be taller than in others, the layout that I have right now, it using a fixed layout_height for the map, what I wanted to be some kind dynamic so I can get remove the scrollview tag

this is my current xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xxxxxxxxx">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_default" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/xxxxxxx"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@color/app_blue_dark"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/xxxxxxx"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/xxxxxxxx"
                android:text="xxxxxxxxx" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/xxxxxxxx"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#666"
                android:text="@string/xxxxxxx"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/xxxxxxxx"
                android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="xxxxxxxxx"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/xxxxxxxx"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/xxxxxxxxxx" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/xxxxxxxxx"
                android:drawablePadding="0dp"
                android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/xxxxxxxx"
                android:onClick="xxxxxxxxx"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/xxxxxxx" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/xxxxxxx"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/xxxxxxx"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="xxxxxxxx"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/xxx"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="xxxxxxxx"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/xxxxxxxxx" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="275dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/xxxx"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
            <TextView
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="xxxxxx" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/xxxx"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                android:lines="2" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `android:weight="1"` and `android:height="0dp"`. That way the map is going to take as much space as it needs, while the rest of the views are displayed as they are. This way you can remove the ScrollView.

Comment: thanks for the response, where should I use the properties? in the map fragment?, because if I did, it make the map alway small and the same size no matter what screen is in, is like is using a default minHeight, but is not doing what I want

Comment: Yes, in the map fragment: `<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         android:layout_weight="1"android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />` . It won't make the map always small, it will have as much space as there's left after the other views have drawn on screen. Could you please try it? :)

Comment: yes, my bad, first time didn't work, now is working perfect, thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Create a linear layout in the fragment then set the Google maps to fill parent since your main layout is a linear layout